# NLTK Named Entity Category Labels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk, jupyter

I keep hitting a wall when it comes to NLTK. I've been able to Token and Categorize a single string of text, however, if I try to apply the script across multiple rows I get the Tokens, but it does not return a Category which is the most important part for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
+nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
nltk.download('words')
SENT_DETECTOR = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
```

Example:

```
ex = 'John'
ne_tree =  nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(ex)))
print(ne_tree)
```

Output:

```
(S (PERSON John/NNP))
```

That is exactly what I'm looking for. I need the Category not just NNP.

When I apply this across a table I just get the token and no Category.

Example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ex3.csv')
df
```

Input:

```
Order   Text
0   0   John
1   1   Paul
2   2   George
3   3   Ringo
```

Code:

```
df['results'] = df.Text.apply(lambda x: nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))))
df
```

Output:

```
print(df)

   Order    Text            results
0      0    John    [[(John, NNP)]]
1      1    Paul    [[(Paul, NNP)]]
2      2  George  [[(George, NNP)]]
3      3   Ringo    [[(Ringo, NN)]]
```

I'm getting the tokens and it's working across all rows, but it is not giving me a Category 'PERSON'.

I really need Categories.

Is this not possible? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go...

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
+nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
nltk.download('words')
df = pd.read_csv("ex3.csv")
# print(df)
text1 = df['text'].to_list()
text =[]
for i in text1:
    text.append(i.capitalize())
# create a column for store resullts
df['results'] = ""

for i in range(len(text)):
    SENT_DETECTOR = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    ne_tree = nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text[i])))
    df['results'][i] = ne_tree[0].label()
print(df)
```

Comment: This works but if I change any of the values to a lower case in the Text field, I get "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'label'". Why would it care about the casing of the first word?

Comment: @JohnnySemicolon I changed the code now it should work